# Get height off divs content on resize - vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got several divs with different content (user specific). These divs are collapsed to a height off 10em, whats the height of it's header. By a click on it it will expand and show up the whole content.
The reason i can't use plain css magic with "height: auto" is a smove expand and collapse animation. Max-Height and different solutions wan't work the way i want it, so it has to be done with javascript.

Javascript

```
//expand & collapse paper
var paperHead = document.getElementsByClassName('paperHead');

for (var i = 0; i < paperHead.length; i++) {
    paperHead[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var selectedPaper = this.parentElement;
        var sectionHeight = selectedPaper.scrollHeight;
        var expanded = selectedPaper.getAttribute('expanded') === 'true';

        if (expanded) {
            this.parentElement.style.height = '10em';
            this.parentElement.removeAttribute('expanded');
        } else {
            selectedPaper.style.height = sectionHeight + 'px';
            selectedPaper.setAttribute('expanded', 'true');
        }
    });

    *here is the resize code included*

}
```

All is working fine and how i expected it. But there is a case where this code isn't enough - if the user resize his window the height won't fit anymore the content. So i tried to add a resize function, but i got to a problem and don't get the point.

Resize-Code:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        var selectedPaper = document.querySelectorAll("[expanded='true']");

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedPaper.length; i++) {
        var actualHeight = selectedPaper[i].scrollHeight;

        selectedPaper[i].style.height = actualHeight + 'px';
    }
});
```

This code is good for 50% of cases. If i decrease the width of my window - all is fine, the divs, which are expanded will increase in height. But the opposite direction isn't working if i increase the width of my window and the div should decrease in height - it doesn't.

I allready got to the point that that's what "scrollHeight" do - it allways get the minimum height the content needs, but won't consider the extra space it allready has and don't need.
I tried offsetHeight, innerHeight, outerHeight and none of those is working for me, so i think i got something wrong with the code itself.

Please just vanilla javascript, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is `expanded` a valid attribute? Also are you trying to "get" or "set" the attribute to true here? `selectedPaper.getAttribute('expanded') === 'true'` It would be good if you could create a minimal example. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm new to javascript, so i don't know if it's a valid attribute. Does it have to be html valid if i set it just for this "expanded-case"? For my understanding i want, for sure, to set this attribute. But i don't know why it's not working if i do selectedPaper.setAttribute('expanded') === 'true'.

Comment: You can create your own attributes and which selectors you can still use/access them but for custom attributes using **`data-expanded`** attribute would be the correct way of doing it. Here is some [**Data attribute documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Ah cool, good to know! Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i got an answer for my own Question ...

it's quite simple - it's done with height: auto on a delay.

```
//expand & collapse paper
var paperHead = document.getElementsByClassName('paperHead');

for (var i = 0; i < paperHead.length; i++) {
    paperHead[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var selectedPaper = this.parentElement;
        var sectionHeight = selectedPaper.scrollHeight;
        var expanded = selectedPaper.getAttribute('expanded') === 'true';

        if (expanded) {
            selectedPaper.style.height = sectionHeight + 'px';

            setTimeout(delay, 1);

            function delay () {
                selectedPaper.style.height = '10em';
                selectedPaper.removeAttribute('expanded');
            }

        } else {
            selectedPaper.style.height = sectionHeight + 'px';
            selectedPaper.setAttribute('expanded', 'true');

            setTimeout(delay1, 150);

            function delay1 () {
                selectedPaper.style.height = 'auto';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If a paperHeader is clicked, it will get the computed height. The transition takes 150ms and after this (delay1, 150), the height will set to "auto". If a paper is expanded and have to collapse on a second click on the paperHeader, the height will set back to the computed one and with a short delay of just 1ms (without the transition - animation won't work) the height will set back to the initial 10em.